# Is the formula for plethysm $S^n(S^3)$ known explicitely?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

Is the formula for plethysm (in this the decomposition into irreducible GL representations of the composition of symmetric powers) $S^n(S^3)$ known explicitely? I know $S^n(S^2)$ e.g. in Macdonald's book. (Also, I am aware of very unexplicit formulas as sums etc.)

Comment: When the plethysm is of representations of $GL_2$ the result is known, and answered here:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/86477/simple-question-in-the-representation-of-sl2-c/86488#86488